# Updating a state variable in React Native Expo

Tags: react-native

I dont really understand how setState and state variables update and work in React Native. Im trying to figure out what I did wrong in the code below, because I'm updating my tokenArray variable, but when I console log it in another function it is empty. Please help.

```
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        tokenArr: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.grabToken()
}

firebaseInformation = async () => {
    var tokens = []
    firebase.database().ref(`tokens/`).once('value', snapshot => {
        const token = Object.values(snapshot.val());
        token.map((item) => {
            tokens.push(item.data)
        })
        return this.setState({
            tokenArr: tokens
        })
    })
}

grabToken = async () => {
    this.firebaseInformation()
    console.log(this.state.tokenArr)
}
```

Comment: `grabToken()` is an asynchronus function, therefore you should use `await this.grabToken()`

Comment: Where do you call firebaseInformation?

Comment: Shivam, are you talking putting an async function inside my component did mount and do await this.grabToken()? I tried that and for some reason it is now not recognizing grabToken as a function. And @RickMcDonald sorry about that, I updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was just to call the grabToken function in my render method instead (I was only calling it from my componentDidMount and didn't understand why it wasn't updating my state variable properly.

Answer (score 0):

Return the array and set the state in componentDidMount() like this

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.firebaseInformation()
  .then((arr) => this.setState({ tokenArr: arr }))
  .then(this.state.tokenArr);
}

firebaseInformation = async () => {
  var tokens = []
  firebase.database().ref(`tokens/`).once('value', snapshot => {
    const token = Object.values(snapshot.val());
    token.map((item) => {
      tokens.push(item.data)
    })
    return tokenArr;
  })
}
```